# I'm trying to run foreground service in android but whenever i run my app, app got freezed and not showing any notification

Tags: java, android, crash, foreground-service

I have created a Notification channel In the onCreate method of MapsActivity and called the method startService to start the service.

**App stay froze until service execution ends**

In logcat Errors caused by is not mentioned. 
I have also mentioned using `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` in ManifestFile

**Main Class**

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "FenceCalculateChannel";
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
createNotificationChannel();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this,BackGroundDistanceCalculate.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
}
public void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Fence Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

**BackGroundDistanceCalculate Service Class**

```
public class BackGroundDistanceCalculate extends Service {

    final public static String TAG = "BackGroundDistance";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        int i;

        for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"Value of i is : "+ i);
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }

        Notification notification =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setContentTitle("Calculating Distance")
                        .setContentText("Distance Calculation is running")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_favorite)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .build();

        //startForeground(1, notification);
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This code should create a Notificationchannel on App start but not working.
What changes may I make to make this App run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service runs works on main thread (UI thread) according to official doc, so it blocked UI, that's why your app freezed.

You should use IntentService which already has a worker thread to run your work.

Or you can manually create an AsyncTask or a Thread inside your service to handle your work.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two things that you can fix to make it work.

1. You are making the `BackGroundDistanceCalculate` go to sleep for 1000 seconds which makes the Main thread to hang on you as instances of `Service` class runs on the Main thread. You can either start up a new thread or extend from IntentService (might not work in Pie+ if not using WorkManager)
2. You can try starting the service using `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()` to start your service and from within your service you will have to post the notification before you start doing your stuff.